How do we handle browser back and forward button
In a webpage using nodeJS and expressJS, once the user is signed in, user can able to go back and forward but once the user is signed out, browser is behaving in same irrespective of signout.
I wanted to handle sessions using cookie for signin and signout(which is already stored in DB). how can we redirect the page once the user is signed out from webpage to signin page.
Note: I am using middleware for routing webpages but I am looking how to manage redirecting once signin and signout
`app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecretKey',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, // set to true if using https
  }
}));

// Serve index page
  app.get('/index', checkSession, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  });

// serve signup page
  app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'signup.html'));
  });


//serve signing page
  app.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'signin.html'));
  });

  // Serve login page
  app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'login.html'));
  });

function checkSession(req, res, next) {
  const sessionId = req.cookies.userSessionId;
  if (!sessionId) {
    console.log("No session ID found in cookie.");
    return res.redirect('/signin');
  }

  const findSessionQuery = 'SELECT host_id FROM active_sessions WHERE session_id = ? AND end_time > NOW()';
  db.query(findSessionQuery, [sessionId], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Error checking session.');
    }
    if (results.length === 0) {
      console.log("Session ID not recognized or expired.");
      return res.redirect('/signin');
    }
    console.log("User is authenticated with session ID:", sessionId);
    req.session.user = { id: results[0].host_id };
    return res.redirect('/login');
  });
}`

